# How to navigate to respective page by tapping RichText in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am implementing RichText, in which while tapping the text i need to navigate to the respective page , i have did it using recognizer, but unable to navigate, any suggestion which could really helpful, pls suggest

```
 RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: ' ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT ? ',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'LOG IN',
                          recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                            )
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent)),
                    ]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping `RichText` in an `InkWell`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextInkwellpage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text InkWell'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell( // child tapped will fire onTap
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(text: 'Inside RichText....', style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style),
          ),
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomePage())),
          // ↑ Navigate to new page here
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
RichText(text: TextSpan(children: [
  TextSpan(
                      text: ' ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT ? ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
  WidgetSpan(child: GestureDetector(child:Text('LOG IN', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),), onTap: (){
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                        );
  },)
]),)
```